# Leibniz property in Coq

Tags: math, coq

I have this definition of equality on natural numbers :

```
Fixpoint equal_nat (n m : nat) : bool := 
  match n, m with
    | O, O => true
    | O, S _ => false
    | S _, O => false
    | S n1, S n2 => equal_nat n1 n2
  end.
```

(which is almost the standard definition)

and I'm trying to prove the following proposition :

```
Proposition equal_nat_correct :
  forall a b : nat, a = b <-> equal_nat a b = true.
```

I can do the first half of the proof, but not the other one... Can you give me a hint ? Here is what i've done so far :

```
Proof.
  intros.
  split.

  (* => *)
  destruct a.
  destruct b.
  reflexivity.
  discriminate.
  intros. destruct H. simpl.
  induction a. reflexivity.
  simpl. assumption.

  (* <= *)
  (* ? *)
Qed.
```

Thanks.

**Edit :**

Here is the complete proof (probably not optimal however) :

```
Proposition equal_nat_correct :
  forall a b : nat, a = b <-> equal_nat a b = true.
Proof.
  split.

  (* => *)
  revert b.
  induction a as [ | a hi]; intros [ | b ]; simpl in *; intuition.
  discriminate.
  discriminate.

  (* <= *)
  revert b.
  induction a.
  intros.
  induction b.
  reflexivity.
  discriminate.
  intros [ | b]; simpl in *; intuition.
  discriminate.  
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea for both half is to go by `induction` but you have to be careful about what is in your context before you perform it. In your particular case, you should not have introduced `b` right away. Here is how I would have done the first half:

```
intros.
split.
revert b. (* puts b back into the goal, so that it is generalized correctly by induction *)
induction a as [ | a hi ]. (* this just gives explicit names to the term newly created by induction *)
  intro [ | b ]. (* this is equalivalent to intro b. destruct b as [ | b ]. *)
    intros; simpl; reflexivity.
    intros; discriminate.

  intro [ | b ].
    intros; discriminate.
    intros h; injection h; intros h2.
    simpl; apply hi; assumption
```

The short version would be:

```
intros.
split.
revert b.
induction a as [ | a hi]; intros [ | b ]; simpl in *; intuition.
discriminate.
discriminate.
```

Following the same pattern (do not forget to generalize `b` in the goal), you should be able to do the second half of the proof.